# App crashing uploading a picture

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, ios-app

Immediately after selecting a photo to upload, the app crashes

Issue is in beta 1.0.1.70
Release 1.0.0 works fine

Comment: I suspect I know the cause.  Looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  I had switched from a vanilla semaphore   (one wait, one signal) to a more thread safe version (many wait, one signal) which happens to assert if it is deallocated while waiting.  The image upload flow ran into this because it created an object to generate a NSURLRequest object but then never used it.

Comment: awesome, thanks. love the detailed explanation too.